# Qt checking the state of multiple buttons

Tags: c++, qt

I am using a StackedLayout and Buttons to switch between screens. I have a separate style for if a button is checked or not. I am also using keyPressEvent to switch between stacks instead of clicking on a button to switch.

When I use the keyPress event, I can switch between stacks, but the buttons don't change from unchecked to checked.

I have 4 buttons and for each I wrote methods to see if the button is checked or not, like so:

```
bool MainWindow::dashBoardButton_isChecked() {
    if(ui->dashBoardButton->isChecked()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    };

    return false;
};
```

and when I switch between stacks, I use this method:

```
void MainWindow::on_dashBoardButton_clicked() {
    ui->mainStack->setCurrentIndex(0);

    if(!dashBoardButton_isChecked()) {
        ui->dashBoardButton->setChecked(true);
    };

};
```

I do this 4 times for each button/stack.  This seems to me to be a little repetitive. Is there some way I could shorten the code, and maybe instead of having 4 very similar methods, have one method that instead?

Comment: Check out `QButtonGroup`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In mainwindow.h add this:

```
#include <QPushButton>
```

and add this prototype:

```
bool isChecked(QPushButton *btn);
```

in mainwindow.c add this function:

```
bool MainWindow::isChecked(QPushButton *btn) {
    if (btn->isChecked())
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Now you can use this function to check if your buttons are checked.

p.s. I've use QPushButton as example.. you have to use the type of your buttons

Answer (score 0):

you might use `QButtonsGroup` or write your own wrapper over group of buttons, so you initialize this wrapper with them providing mapping between button and some value describing which of them is checked, you can connect each button to slot of this wrapper to update value and you might signal this change from a wrapper using signal-slot mechanism. You might use `QSignalMapper`.

```
Keypad::Keypad(QWidget *parent)
        : QWidget(parent)
    {
        QSignalMapper *signalMapper = new QSignalMapper(this);
        connect(signalMapper,SIGNAL(mapped(int)),this,SIGNAL(digitClicked(int)));

        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
            QString text = QString::number(i);
            buttons[i] = new QPushButton(text, this);
            signalMapper->setMapping(buttons[i], i);
            connect(buttons[i], SIGNAL(clicked()), signalMapper, SLOT(map()));
        }

        createLayout();
    }
```

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qsignalmapper.html

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq10-signalmapper.html